# Find Method usages only for specified class in Intelij-Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and I have problem with method usage finding.

Suppose I have interface Worker.

```
public interface Worker {
    
    void startWork();
    void endWork();
}
```

And I have two implementations.

```
public class Develper implements Worker {
    @Override
    public void startWork() {
        System.out.println("Developer Start Working");
    }

    @Override
    public void endWork() {

    }
}

public class Qa implements Worker {
    @Override
    public void startWork() {
        System.out.println("QA start Work");
    }

    @Override
    public void endWork() {

    }
}
```

I open the Developer class and trying to find usages of `startWork()`.
I want only to view usage of the `Developer.startWork()` implemented method.

But when I find usages it shows both Developer and `Qa.startWork()` method usages. How can I avoid `Qa.startWork()` method usage when finding `Developer.startWork()` usages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1 .

I think what you see when using the "find usages" functionality depends from the context.

If you place the cursor in method name `Developer.startWork` and invoke `find usages` , you should see a small dialog. You are asked "Do you want to find usages of the base method?" .

If you say "No", and in your sources you did only call the method via the base class or interface (`Worker.start()` in your example), IDEA doesn't show you any hits. Thats correct.

If you call the overridden method via `Developer.startWork()` , and press "No" in the dialog, then you will see the usages of the specific implementation.

**Update:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply. but sorry to say i cant find such a option. still show same result.

Answer (score 15):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> for Mac) should show the prompt from Jim Hawkins answer.

See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-usages-method-options.html

> When you search for usages of a method implementation with this dialog Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F7, IntelliJ IDEA will ask whether or not you want to search for the base method. With any other find usages actions such as Alt+F7 or Ctrl+Alt+F7, the base method will be included in the search results automatically.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the answer from @JimHawkins, I think the elephant is still in the room :) The question is, do you want to see where `Developer.startWork()` is actually called, or do you want to see where it is statically referenced?

Eg:

```
Developer developer = new Developer();
developer.startWork(); // you want to find only this?
Worker worker = developer;
worker.startWork(); // ..or this as well?
```

The find usages method can only tell, where a given method is statically referenced, but not where it is actually used (that is determined runtime via the mechanism of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping)).